# How to let admin upload background image for view page and webform page?

Tags: 7, media

I would like admin to upload background image for each and every different pages in my drupal 7 site.

For normal content type like basic page, BackgroundField module works perfectly where admin can upload images in the file field.

But in webform pages and pages created by view, BackgroundField module can't be used.

Is there any way admin can upload their background image for both webform pages and view pages? As currently I'm using css to set the background images for these pages.

Answer (score 0):

This module can do it for you [Background Images](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image).

Comment: But this is adding background image according to content type? I need different background images even they are the same content type (Eg: 2 different webforms)

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter this module extends it's functionality. Try reading the documentations also